# Return xml file on client from a asp.net mvc web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web page which asks for user input to fill in some info. The javascript function to create the xml is called on a button click after user enters the information. How do I return the xml to the user created by this javascript method?

In the .cshtml file:
Lets say we have a text box.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="NameTextBox" name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a name ..." class="form-control" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
</div>
<input id="CreateXml" type="submit" class="btn" value="Create XML" onclick="javascript:createXml()" />
```

In the .js file:

```
function createXml() {

    var returnXml = "<Hello>" + "\n";
    var name = $('#NameTextBox').text();
    returnXml = returnXml + name + "\n" + </Hello>;

}
```

How do I return the returnXml string in a file on the client? I don't think we need to post to a Action (using ajax may be) in the Home controller but if that is a solution I would like to know it as well.

Comment: How do you want to return this XML to the client? As a Save As file dialog or something? Also why is your question tagged with `ajax`. Is there any relation to this particular technology with your question?

Comment: Yes, Save As dialog would work.

Comment: Forget about it. Can't do it with javascript only. This should be handled by the server if you need Save As dialog.

Comment: Can it be done using the file writer api - http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/

Comment: I don't know if this is possible in IE only (but that would work too). How can we use blob writer to return xml file with save as dialog: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542(v=vs.85).aspx , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/27/creating-files-through-blobbuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I was able to get this done with:

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([returnXml], { type: "text/xml" }));
```

It opens up the save or open dialog with a GUID file name. One can pass the file name as param to the msSaveOrOpenBlob method as well.

(This works with IE11, will have to check for other browsers on this kind of support. )